# This use case is not supported on instagram api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to get the "My app allows non-business users to login and post comments, likes or follow actions" permission on Instagram but I am getting the following error:

> This use case is not supported. The likes, comments and relationships
>   permissions are granted to products that enable businesses to manage
>   communication with people who have expressed interest in them. We do
>   not approve use of these permissions for non-business purposes.

How can I get this permission for my app?

Answer (score 0):

You cant - look at Instagram Graph API

Comment: why i cant? Graph API works for business accounts only!

Comment: Because you want non-business users to login, which they cannot because they are non-business and not business.